# Have textview contain links inside a listview

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a problem catching clicks on links.

You can have links shown by using this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/newsListview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:autoLink="all"        
    >
</ListView>

// **s** contains mixed text with multiple links in    
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

However, which clicking inside the textview, the event is caught by

```
  OnItemClickListener eventClickListener = new OnItemClickListener()  
  {                                
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
    {                           
      MyListItemExt data = myItemsDataArrayList.get(position);              
      //...
      Intent paramIntent = new Intent(thisActivityContext, Browser.class);
      //...
    }
  }
  newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(eventClickListener);
```

Some people suggest using

```
textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

but 1) it seems to disable all links and 2) I do not understand reading the doc why this would help

Now, I have seen some suggestions on using an intent filter (to avoid external browser for opening), but as long as the click is caught by the listview, I do not think it will make any diffeence since the link click is not caught att all as far as I can tell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convertView loses onitemClick after the listView is scrolled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863662/convertview-loses-onitemclick-after-the-listview-is-scrolled)

Answer (score 0):

In the XML of the textview, add the lines

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

And then, for the entire view (the linear or relative layout that contains your row), add an `onClickListener` within `getView()`. It's not elegant, but it's the way I've had to do it before.

Comment: Does not solve the problem described? There is no problem in having the links shown (indeed I am already doing what you describe, just using "all" instead of "web" as value, but I have tried both), it is the actual opening of links that do not work (for me) when (I guess) the textview is placed on a listview that catches the clicks

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't read the entire question (which I feel really dumb for). Better answer posted.

Comment: I have **setOnItemClickListener** on the **listview** I think you suggesting adding **setOnClickListener** on the **textview** (i.e. there's a textview in each item in the listview)? But how do you identify which link in the text was clicked?

Comment: Nope, like I said in the answer, on the layout view. Each row is inflated from some layout, whose root is a `*Layout` view, for example `LinearLayout`. That is what you set the `onClickListener` on

Comment: Okay, I understand now. However, I am still a litle confused on how this will allow me to grab and respond to clicks on e.g. the 2nd of 3 links (in mixed text) in the text inside the TextView?

Comment: Because you don't have a onclicklistener in the list view, that will not intercept the clicks anymore.

Comment: It does not seem to make a difference. However, with some experimentation, I do catch the click event on the textview now. However, I am still unsuccessful at having a browser open when clicking the links inside the text in the textview. Will try searc some more.