# TextView with autoLink="web" inside ListView has animation issue

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have a ListView. There is a TextView for each list row. For the TextView, I have set the following properties in the xml file:

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Also, for the parent layout of the list row, I have set:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

The three focus-related properties were set after going through several SO answers for the problem in which the TextView used to become un-clickable if it contained a link (e.g., www.example.com).

Now the clicks are all registered properly. However, the problem now is the following: for TextViews which have a link, the `setOnItemClickListener` and `setOnItemLongClickListener` animations are lost. The animations are lost only when I click the `TextView` part of the ListView row. They still occur when I click the remaining part of the ListView row.

That is, the clicks are working, but the animation is lost. How do I get those back?

Comment: which interface are you using for onlongpress for listview

Comment: @AnilMeenugu edited my question. I am using the default listeners.

Comment: post your code what you did

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?